# Where can I find Equipment?

Tags: ramble-planet

So I just noticed the equipment value (Eqmt) in my character status.

It says 1 piece of equipment raises your level by one.  I'm guessing I'll need several pieces to be able to take on the higher level Badmark denizens.

Where can I find some?

[image: 1 Equipment = 1 level]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m Willy, the creator of Ramble Planet. Gaining equipment increases your Level. There are 5 pieces of equipment.

The very center of The Desert is surrounded by skull-shaped walls. Some of the passages through these walls teleport you. In the middle of these walls are some pillars. One tile of pillars looks different than the others and contains a hidden switch. This switch reveals a chest that contains a piece of equipment.

On The Wall is a dying robot creature. If you speak with him, he explains that his mother killed him. After that, his mother appears on the wall. She is Level 3 and partially invisible. If you find her and defeat her, you will earn another piece of equipment.

Inside a grave in The Cemetery is a piece of equipment. There are clues as to which grave if you read some of the other gravestones.

Underground, in one of the west chambers of crypt/pyramid is a purple sarcophagus that contains a piece of equipment. Of course, you have to navigate the maze of one-way ramps to get there.

Underground, there is a robot on an island in the river. He is west of the grove/garden area. If you have 100 Experience, he will give you a piece of equipment.